# Upload file to share folder/ map drive in localhost using PHP (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, localhost, sharefile

I have two computers C1 and C2 both computers running the same WordPress website and connected to each other using a switch. I can access C1 from C2 in Networks.

I am using a custom plugin in which I am uploading files, each computer upload files in their specific folder, uploads/XYZ.

What I want is to save the uploaded file of C2 to C1 uploads/XYZ folder. So that I can access uploaded files from C1 and I don't need to go to the C2.

Right now I share and give all permissions to the /XYZ folder of C1 and this folder is accessible from C2.

In my code, I provide the shared folder path but it didn’t works, also I made the shared folder as a mapped drive it also not works.

Here is my code:

```
$upload_dir = ‘\\C1\XYZ’;

if(!is_dir($upload_dir))
 mkdir($upload_dir);



$img = $_POST[‘form1_data1’];
$name = $_POST[‘form1_data2’];
$img = str_replace(‘\\’, ”, $img);
$file = $upload_dir .’/’. $name . “.svg”;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $img);
echo $name;
die();
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks